# Links from the_tag not working

Tags: tags

I am using Wordpress to output different content types here: http://www.africanhealthleadership.org/resources/articles/

Each type of content is tagged accordingly.  Users should be able to click on these tags & see all items marked with that tag e.g. clicking the word "Article" above the article name would take someone to a full list of articles.

However, the tag links are not working: clicking does nothing.

This is the code I used to output the tag and  article name.
`

`
When I check the page with Firebug, I see a link such as

Is the rel preventing the links from working? Or is it my goofy little brain?

Thanks for any ideas,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

i checked firebug, are you displaying the tags by using  `<?php the_tags(); ?>` ? if not, what else are you using ?

I hope this links helps 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I used this: <h3><?php the_tags(''); ?></h3>

Comment: try using <?php the_tags(); ?> - remove the ''  - i re-formatted my answer

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.